# mysql statement to show either table or message

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I have an order table in my database and once a user logs into his account, he/she can view his/her previous orders.

I have the following code for it:

```
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."' ")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

echo "<table border='0'><table border width=100%><tr><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Date</th>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['quantity']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['price']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

what mysql statement do i use to show a message 'you have not ordered anything yet' instead of a blank table?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get the number of rows in the resultset.

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows == 0) {
   echo 'you have not ordered anything yet';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."' ")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'you have not ordered anything yet';
    } else {
    echo "<table border='0'><table border width=100%><tr><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Date</th>";
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['quantity']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['price']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
    
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of results in your statement using [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo '<p>You have not ordered anything yet.</p>';
}
else {
  echo "<table...";
}
```

Also, you probably want to move the second to last line (`echo "</tr>";`) inside your `while` loop so the HTML is outputted correctly.